# TPROXY - Get the accurate destination/remote IP address

Tags: linux, sockets, transparentproxy

Using the latest TPROXY with the Linux Kernel, how would I get the IP address of the remote/destination machine? I am assuming that the local/source endpoint is returned from `accept()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original (before rerouting) remote destination will be in `getsockname()`. `accept()` will return the local (local enough BUT NOT an interface on the computer) source address.